# Convert the Custom Regex rule to Laravel validator

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5

I have multiple forms(>20), I was looking for a validate the form input fields using Regex.

Instead of manually filling the regex to validate the controller, I would like to create a new rule and call the rull for the validation.

Just incase, if I need to update the regex pattern, I can do it in once place and dont have to do it in all the forms manually.

I am not sure how do I add the Regex pattern to the rules.

My steps:

```
php artisan make:rule MobileNo
```

My regex patterns,

For validating Phone no as well as land Phone no

```
`regex:/(^[0-9]+$)+/`
```

Validation for title:

> `regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9@ ()%,:<>?*&-]+$)+/`

Please guide me how do I acheive it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After `make:rule` command you will see that one file was created under rules folder.
In that file you have to define rules as follows

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return preg_match('/(^[0-9]+$)+/', $value);
}
```

and in your controller you can do something like this

```
use App\Rules\MobileNo;

$rules = [
        'phone' => ['required', new MobileNo],
    ];
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

**regex:pattern**

The field under validation must match the given regular expression.

**Note:** When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead >of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

**To clarify:** you would do something like this.

```
$regex_rules = array('test' => array('size:6', 'regex:foo'));

'cid' => array('required', 'regex:/^((comp)|(soen)|(engr)|(elec))\d{3}$/i'),

'description'=>'required|regex:/^[A-Za-z \t]*$/i|min:3|unique:courses',

'credits'=>'required|regex:/^\d+(\.\d)?$/'
```